# Devise scope controller not found

Tags: devise, ruby-2.1, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I created the following devise scope:

```
devise_scope :users do get
  get 'spotkey'     => 'spotkeys#spot_page'
  get 'dashboard'     => 'spotkeys#dashboard'
  post 'dashboard'    => 'spotkeys#dashboard'
  get 'signup' => 'users/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'signin'=> 'users/sessions#create',  :as => :user_session
  delete 'signout' => 'users/sessions#destroy'
end
```

controllers/users.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end


  def dashboard
    @keys     = Spotkeys.all
    @keys     = Spotkeys.new
    @spotkeys = Spotkeys.all
    @spotkeys = Spotkeys.new
  end
end
```

views/spotkeys/dashboard.hrml.erb

```
<div class="key">
  <%= @keys.location %><br/>
  <%= @keys.picture_url %><br/>
  <%= @keys.floor_number %><br/>
  <%= @keys.description %><br/>
  <%= @keys.floor %><br/>
  <%= @keys.buzzer_code %><br/>
  <%= @keys.parking_info %><br/>
  <%= @keys.cross_street %><br/>
  <%= @keys.public_transit %>
</div>
```

I'm getting the follow error:

```
missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes
```

Please let me know if you need to see any other files.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I noticed:

1. Regarding to [this comment](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2840#issuecomment-67783871) and [devise how-to wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes), `devise_scope` needs the resource name in **singular** (`devise_for`, in contrary, needs the resource name in **plural**).
2. You also have a weird `get` on the same line with `devise_scope`- it might cause the problem.

[Routing mapper](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/actionpack/4.0.4/symbols/ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Mapping#line=229), from where the error is raised, also suggests that it does not find such controller. It probably tries to search a controller based on your *plural form* of `devise_scope`. OR it tries to find controller name after your extra-`get` keyword after `:users do`.